# Why does this carbocation undergo further rearrangement?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbocation, rearrangements

> [image]

I am trying to figure out the product of this reaction. I initially thought that a carbocation would be formed at where the chlorine leaves
from:

> [image]

But according to the answer stated by the textbook, it should be this:

> [image]

But why does this rearrangement have to occur? Isn't the carbocation quite stable already?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the entire question with the answer too? Or you just have to form the carbocation?

Comment: As comment above. However carbocation re-arrangement is a real thing. Though this example isn't even what is commonly intended by the term. It is not clear if you where introduced to the argument. I can't believe that was done by this example, though.

Comment: @RandomQuark There is no problem statement given in my book. I am just supposed to form the carbocation. And I have stated the answer as well.

Comment: I don't know if it's actually a rearrangement or more of several resonance structures of the same species.

Comment: @ShoubhikRMaiti that it what I also think and said above. Out of nothing this is a difficult exercise. It is a kind of hyoerconjugation complicated by the visual.

Comment: @Alchimista Yes I agree with you. I think OP is confusing resonance with rearrangement (which has to involve movement of whole atoms)

Comment: I find some similarity in this case and this one- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbouring_group_participation, see NGP of an alkene, but I'm unable to figure out the exact answer.

Comment: This is not a rearrangement, they are resonance structures of a so-called "non-classical" carbocation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-Norbornyl_cation

Comment: @orthocresol Thanks for the link. I think I found my answer.

Comment: @ShoubhikRMaiti According to the link provided by orthocresol, I believe you are right. I asked my teacher about it yesterday, who said that its called 'Wagner-Meerwein Rearrangement'. Now that I have gone through the link, I am convinced it is just a depiction of the resonance structures.

Comment: Yes it is a depiction of several resonance structures, it's definitely not Wagner-Meerwein rearrangement, because that involved movement of an H.